# How to find out if a pdf file is "blocked" by a pdf-reader

Tags: c, winapi, pdf-reader

In our application you can import - for instance - a pdf file into the application area. In the popup window where you define the path of the pdf file, you can specify if the original file should be deleted after a successful import or not.

Sometimes a user imports a pdf file, which he has also "open" in an pdf reader (in our case pdf xchange viewer and foxit reader). In this case our application cannot delete the pdf file because it is somehow blocked.

How can I find out - for instance a winapi call? (without trying to delete it or rename it) that the pdf is blocked by a pdf reader?

Thanks alot in advance

Comment: *"How can I find out that the pdf is blocked by a pdf reader?"* - By trying to delete it.

Comment: Are you using the `DeleteFile` function?

Comment: You never want to find out if you can do something involving the outside world before you do it because there's a good chance that you will be preempted after the check. If, by the time you start running again, the condition has changed, it's too late and you'll still act like the situation was as it stood before. This is called a "time of check to time of use" bug, and even though in this case it's relatively harmless, it can be applied in other places and become serious security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Though it is not good to interfere with other programs (just tell your user the file is being used), releasing file locks are a bit difficult.

- First, you need to use `ZwQuerySystemInformation` to obtain a system-wide file handle table (and your program needs SeDebug privilege) and find the file being used.

  - Use `DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE` flag for `DuplicateHandle` to duplicate and close the file handle.
  - Or, go into the kernel and use `ZwClose` or ObDereference functions to close a file.

Still, closing a file outside may crash remote programs and it is against Windows' design principles.